# Объекту класса передать словарь

Tags: python, ооп

В коде два класса. В базовом создан словарь. Подскажите как при создании объекта производного класса присвоить ему значение этого словаря и дальше с ним работать как со словарём используя стандартные методы?

Код:

```
class Gifts:

    def __init__(self):
        self.gifts = dict()

    def add(self, value):
        if value in self.gifts.keys():
            self.gifts[value] = int(self.gifts[value]) + 1
        else:
            self.gifts[value] = 1

    def get_gifts(self):
        return sorted(list(self.gifts.keys()))

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Gifts()'


class GhostGifts(Gifts):
    pass
```

Пример ввода:

```
gg = GhostGifts()
print(gg[key])
print(len(gg))
```

Необходимый вывод:

```
value
32
```

Comment: А что должно выступать ключом, можете уточнить?

Comment: Вообще, если вы хотите использовать свой класс, как модифицированный словарь, то вы можете унаследовать родительский класс от него. Тем самым вам не понадобится самому переопределять всю логику. По типу магические методов len, getitem и других.

Comment: Что подразумевается под "дальше с ним работать как со словарём используя стандартные методы"?  В чём проблема в init дочернего класса определить значение?

Comment: Ключом будут выступать различные строки. Словарь формируется методом add.

Comment: Подозреваю, что это не сложно, но я в ООП - новичок)

Comment: В примере сразу после создания объекта, вы обращаетесь к этому объекту по предполагаемому ключу. Вы же понимаете, что словарь в любом случае  надо заполнить, это можно сделать в момент создания объекта, например, заполнив его ключами от 1 до 32(у вас указана такая длина) и такими же значениями. Но, возможно вы хотите немного другое заполнение, например в момент создания вы можете передавать **kwargs, и тем самым заполнить словарь.

Comment: Если вопрос обстоит только с тем, что вы хотите обращаться к объекту через [key] и иметь возможность его выводить используя функцию print(), то в таком случае я могу показать такую реализацию.

Comment: Заполнение словаря осуществляется по коду, не внутри класса. Тут все работает.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как обратиться объекту через [key]  и вывести используя функцию print()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы использовать оператор [] нужно перегрузить такой магический метод, как getitem, а для вывода в термина str, выглядеть это будет вот так:

```
class Gifts:

    def __init__(self):
        self.gifts = dict()

    def add(self, value):
        if value in self.gifts.keys():
            self.gifts[value] = int(self.gifts[value]) + 1
        else:
            self.gifts[value] = 1

    def get_gifts(self):
        return sorted(list(self.gifts.keys()))

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Gifts()'

    # Для оператора []
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.gifts[item]

    # Для print()
    def __str__(self):
        return ''.join(f'key: {key}, value: {value};\n' for key, value in self.gifts.items())


class GhostGifts(Gifts):
    pass


someGift = GhostGifts()
someGift.add(4)
someGift.add('SomeStr')
print(someGift[4])
print(someGift)
```

Вывод:

```
1
key: 4, value: 1;
key: SomeStr, value: 1;
```

Но стоит заметить, что наследование класса Gifts от dict, было бы куда проще, тогда бы передался весь функционал данной структуры, и тогда можно было бы думать только о модифицировании функционала, а не о его добавлении.